# compare lines txt document python

Tags: python

This part of my script is meant to compare a website page with a text document of the last time it ran.
The problem I am having though is that it only returns 1 line that has changed and ignores everything after that?

What do i need to change to make so that move everything across?

```
def moo(DocIn, DocOut, WebAddy, Pub, Pub2, PDF): 
    os.rename(DocIn, DocOut) # Renames the old compare document to 2
    file(DocIn, "wb").write(urllib2.urlopen(WebAddy).read()) # Creates a new document to compare from
    hosts0 = open(DocIn,"rb")
    hosts1 = open(DocOut,"rb")
    lines1 = hosts0.readlines()
    for i, lines2 in enumerate(hosts1):
        if lines2 != lines1[i]:
            chgdoc(DocOut, lines2)
            print "line ", i, " in hosts1 is different \n"
            print lines2

def chgdoc(DocOut, lines2):
    fileName, fileExtension = os.path.splitext(DocOut)
    file = open(fileName + '_3' + fileExtension, "a")
    file.write(lines2)
    file.close()
```

Comment: Creates a new document of what has changed.

Comment: It's a bad idea to iterate over something that is changing. Define lines2 like you have defined lines1. That just might do it.

Comment: Is your chgdoc() method creating a new document the first time and then appending the lines to it ? I think you might be overwriting the document in the loop. It would be better if you could show us what chgdoc is like. Another thing would be use Python's with operator while working with files.

Comment: Try `enumerate(hosts1.readlines())`? Also, try to print the things over which you are iterating to see what's going on inside your loop.